# Emacs: How do i move the cursor directly to (interactive command line?) without a mouse

Tags: emacs

How do I move the cursor directly here

[image: Where I want to move the cursor]

without a mouse?

Comment: you can refer to [this link][1], same question.


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/132225/how-to-get-back-to-an-active-minibuffer-prompt-in-emacs-without-the-mouse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current situation, you can use <kbd>M-minus</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>, or press <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> twice. <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> invokes the `other-window` function which moves the cursor to the next window, prefixing it with `-` moves it to the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

This is a better way to select the minibuffer, regardless from where your point is set now, and won't do anything when there actually is no minibuffer.

I actually copied the [answer](https://superuser.com/a/132454) (since this is a duplicate question)  from [Trey Jackson](https://superuser.com/users/1474/trey-jackson)

```
(defun switch-to-minibuffer-window ()
  "switch to minibuffer window (if active)"
  (interactive)
  (when (active-minibuffer-window)
    (select-window (active-minibuffer-window))))

(global-set-key (kbd "<f7>") 'switch-to-minibuffer-window)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you enable `(windmove-default-keybindings)` then you can select the minibuffer simply by typing <kbd>S-<down></kbd> (to switch to the window below the one you're in) as many times as necessary.